# Apache Drill - Get max directory in each path?

Tags: apache-drill

Drill lets you query multiple directories simultaneously, and lets you control which ones with the dir0/dir1/etc variables.

It also lets you find the MAXDIR or MINDIR with its directory functions.  So, you can, for example, write a new version of files in a directory and ensure drill always uses the newest one.

Is there a way to query the newest version of each leaf directory though?  For example.

- 2018/

  - 01/

    - v1/
    - v2/
  - 02/

    - v1/
    - v2/

I'd like to select only the data in the v2 directories for each month.  So, dir0 would be 2018, dir1 would be *, and I'd want the MAX(dir2).

I was thinking of something like this:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM dfs.`/path/drill-data/`
where
dir0 = '2018' and dir1 = '*' and dir3 = MAXDIR('dfs', dir1);
```

but it doesn't seem to work; it says something about a null-related error with the MAXDIR function.  I suspect I need to provide a full path as the second parameter but then I think it would probably choose a single max directory and not one per leaf folder.

Answer (score 2):

**Figured it out.**

- If a directory variable would be a wild-card, just don't put it in the where clause.
- Use concat() to build the path using the dir variables for the second parameter of MAXDIR.  This way you can make a path based on the current values of the DIR variables on the current record.

**For example**

Note that this example has some extra directory levels.

```
SELECT distinct epoch_hour, concat(dir0, '-', dir1, '-', dir2, '-', dir3) as origin
FROM dfs.`/path/drill-data/`
where
dir0 = '2018' and dir1 = '01'
and dir3 = MAXDIR('dfs', concat('/path/drill-data/', dir0, '/', dir1, '/', dir2, '/'))
```